# Building mavenized MuleStudio project

Tags: maven, mule, mule-studio

I have a mavenized Mule project in MuleStudio. When I try to package using maven it starts downloading some EE jar files from http://dev.ee.mulesource.com/repository/...

I have no EE dependencies in my POM.xml.

1. Why is maven trying to download these dependencies?
2. Maven is just pulling pom files only (and not related jar files). Why ?

   ```
   Downloading: http://dev.ee.mulesource.com/repository/content/repositories/releas
   es/com/ibm/icu/icu4j-normalizer_transliterator/4.8.1.1/icu4j-normalizer_translit
   erator-4.8.1.1.pom
   Downloading: http://dev.ee.mulesource.com/repository/content/repositories/snapsh
   ots/com/ibm/icu/icu4j-normalizer_transliterator/4.8.1.1/icu4j-normalizer_transli
   terator-4.8.1.1.pom
   Downloading: http://dev.ee.mulesource.com/repository/content/repositories/ext-re
   leases/com/ibm/icu/icu4j-normalizer_transliterator/4.8.1.1/icu4j-normalizer_tran
   sliterator-4.8.1.1.pom
   Downloading: https://repository-lsi.forge.cloudbees.com/release/com/googlecode/s
   ardine/sardine/248/sardine-248.pom
   Downloading: http://dev.ee.mulesource.com/repository/content/repositories/releas
   es/com/googlecode/sardine/sardine/248/sardine-248.pom
   Downloading: http://dev.ee.mulesource.com/repository/content/repositories/snapsh
   ots/com/googlecode/sardine/sardine/248/sardine-248.pom
   ```

Comment: Seems like repitition of the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505495/how-does-mule-ide-create-pom-xml-why-it-is-adding-ee-dependencies

Answer (score 5):

These are **DataMapper** dependencies. To use it you need an enterprise edition license.

If you have purchased a subscription you can get access to MuleSoft's Enterprise Edition (EE) Nexus repository, otherwise simply remove the **datamapper** dependency and the **clover-etl** one from your pom.

Comment: Looking at the name of the server in the URL (from where it is apparently trying to download jars) **http://dev.ee.mulesource.com**, it seems that somehow the source code is trying to connect to some DEV server.

Comment: Instead of http://dev.ee.mulesource.com/repository/content/repositories/releases, it should go to https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/.